# How to load a bitmap image from a file and show it on screen using Direct2D (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c++, bitmap, directx, windows-phone-8.1, direct2d

The title says everything. I am trying to take a .png image and convert it to a ID2D1Bitmap, then draw that bitmap to the screen. Here is my code so far:

```
HRESULT hr;
IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory = NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap **bitmap = NULL;
IWICBitmapDecoder *decoder = NULL;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode *bitmapSrc = NULL;
IWICStream *stream = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter *converter = NULL;
IWICBitmapScaler *scaler = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID+WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
     IID_PPV_ARGS(&wicFactory));


hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(L"filestring", NULL< GENERIC_READ,
         WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, &decoder);
hr = decoder->GetFrame(0, &bitmapSrc);
hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
hr = converter->Initialize(bitmapSrc, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
     WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
hr = context1->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, bitmap);

context1->BeginDraw();
D2D1_SIZE_F size = (*bitmap)->GetSize();
D2D1_POINT_2F ulc = D2D1::Point2F(100.f, 10.f);
context1->DrawBitmap(*bitmap, D2D1::RectF(ulc.x, ulc.y, ulc.x + size.width,
          ulc.y+size.height));

DX::ThrowIfFailed(context1->endDraw();
```

Now some of the above is out of context. Context1 is the rendering target. I continually get the error that I am causing a reading violation. It is coming from the call for (*bitmap)->GetSize(); Now I do believe this method is right. However, if anyone has a better idea, please feel free to offer it.

Comment: Try:ID2D1Bitmap *bitmap = NULL; and then: context1->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &bitmap);